# Accessing website from within the LAN via web address

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting, networking

I run a small website at my house; just started it up the other day running Wordpress. The problem I'm facing is fairly obvious: I need to access my website, but I can't use the URL due my hosting on the same network I'm trying to access from. I use Chrome, and when I try to load the page it says that it simply could not connect.

My question is simple: how can I access my site, Wordpress running through Apache on Ubuntu 12.10 LAMP stack, on the same network that I'm hosting it from without the use of proxy or VPN?

Answer (score 1):

you can modify your host file to point to this url. here you can see how modify host file [modify host file](http://practice.chatserve.com/hosts.html)

Comment: That didn't work at all. I knew how to do this already, I had to for hosting multiple domains. I need to be able to access from WITHIN the network.

Comment: did you try install a "local dns server", with that you'll be able to define the zones and the ip.